# Check machine code of a line

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm trying to do a simple binary exploitation, but the machine code isn't what I was expecting.

```
0x080484ed <+57>:   test   %eax,%eax
0x080484ef <+59>:   je     0x8048507 <echo+83>
```

What does the 0x8048507 after je mean? The opcode of je is 74, so I would've expected the opcode to be something like 0x8048574. Follow-up question, assuming that 0x8048507 isn't the machine code of the statement, how do I see/modify the machine code (change the 74 to a 75, so it performs the jump)?

e: I found the 74 by putting a breakpoint on the je line and running x/x $pc. How do I modify it?

Comment: One of the  [_JE_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html) opcodes is 0x74 but it takes a 1 byte operand that represents a relative value from the start of the instruction after _JE_. 0x8048507 is the computed address of that relative value added to the instruction pointer of the next instruction.

Comment: If using _GDB_ `set *(char*)0x080484ef  = 0x75` . 0x080484ef  is the address of the beginning of the _JE_ instruction.

Comment: Yup, that worked. So when you do set *(char*) on an address, it modifies the last halfword?

Comment: It sets the byte at memory address 0x080484ef to 75. 0x080484ef is the start of the instruction where the 0x74 opcode would have been.

Comment: So let's say it was big endian and the command was 0x741683ec. What would the command be then?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I think it is more useful for you (if that output is from GDB) to use `disassemble /r 0x080484ed` it will show you each byte of the instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x8048507 is the address you jump to. The opcode of `je` is `0x74` as you can see using a decent disassembler (e.g. objdump). Also confer [this table](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html).

Comment: I set a breakpoint at the jump address and ran x/x $pc, the output was 0xec831674. So I found the 74. How do I change it to a 75?

Comment: Changing 74 to 75 changes the operation to some other kind of jump. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yup, I want to change the je to jne to change the flow of the program. I got it working though

Comment: @user3364161 Fantastic!